# Foreach txt and image files with different code blocks

Tags: php, html

I have a gallery. I would like to glob files into. It works fine for jpg, png etc.

Directory:

1.jpg

2.png

3.jpg
...

Code :

```
foreach ($gallery as $u)   
{ 
echo'<div class="section active" id="">'; 

foreach (glob("$meno/$new/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,txt}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {

    echo '<div class="slide"><img class="" src="https://onlinegallery.online/'.$filename.'" /></div>';  //slide
}

echo('</div>');
}
```

I would like to put a txt file to directory and create foreach for txt and image files (Some slides should be a txt files). I don't know how to do that because txt file can't be used in img src tag. It should looks something like this.

Directory:

1.png

2.img

3.txt

4.jpg

```
$images = '<img class="" src="https://onlinegallery.online/'.$filename.'" />';

$txt = '<div><p>fopen("'.$filename.'", "r");
             echo fread($txt,filesize("'.$filename.'"));
             fclose($txt); </p></div>';

foreach ($gallery as $u)   
{ 
echo'<div class="section active" id="">'; 

foreach (glob("$meno/$new/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,txt}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {

    echo '<div class="slide"> 

//$images or $txt files
//i need txt and images files here

</div>';  //slide
}

echo('</div>');
}
```

I suppose I'm completely out, but thank you for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to read the contents of your text files and output them. Be careful to sanitize the text contents - you don't want to accidentally emit something that's treated as html, especially if the contents are coming from an unknown source ([read more](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Code_Injection)).

You'll also need to add an `if` inside the for loop to determine if you're outputting an image or text. For images, you can keep using your existing code.

For text, something like this might work:

```php
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($filepath));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helped me to solve it. I don't know if the code is correct but works ( im terrible coder ). Do you thing that the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING on bellow code is sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (glob("$meno/$new/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,txt}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {

        $imgFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $title = basename("$meno/$new/$filename", ".jpg").PHP_EOL;

        if(($imgFileType == 'jpg') || ($imgFileType == 'png') || ($imgFileType == 'jpeg') || ($imgFileType == 'gif')) {
    echo '<div class="slide"><img class="" onclick="fullscreen()" src="https://onlinegallery.online/'.$filename.'" alt="'.$title.'"/><p class="imagetitle">'.$title.'</p></div>'; 
}

        if(($imgFileType == 'txt')) {

    echo '<div class="slide"><p class="txtslide" onclick="fullscreen()">';
    echo filter_var(file_get_contents($filename), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    echo '</p><p class="imagetitle">'.$title.'</p></div>';     
}


}


echo('</div>');
```